# SQLAlchemy TypeDecorator for BigInteger returns Decimal?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create a Type converter on SQLAlchemy that takes a `BIGINTEGER` from the database, and converts it to a Base64 value.

The problem is that, for some reasons, the value coming from the database is not an `int`, but a `decimal.Decimal`. I suspect this is linked to the BigInteger class I use (from the MySQL dialect instead of the `BIGINT` from SQLAlchemy because I need to set the unsigned parameter).

Any idea how to get the value from the database as `int` and not as `decimal.Decimal` ?

Here's my current implementation:

```
class B64ID(types.TypeDecorator):
    impl = BIGINT  # from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql import BIGINT

    def __init__(self, prefix):
        self.prefix = prefix
        self.impl.unsigned = True
        types.TypeDecorator.__init__(self, unsigned=self.impl.unsigned)

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect=None):
        return int(base64.b64decode(value.encode()))

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect=None):
        print(value, value.__class__)  # Here, in some case, the class is decimal.Decimal!
        return base64.b64encode(str(value).encode()).decode()
```

How can I define that the value coming from the database is not a `decimal.Decimal`, but an `int` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BIGINT is returned to you as a python int, not a Decimal. The problem is likely that you didn't actually create the database column as a BIGINT.

Comment: You are right... The trick on my side was that all the elements are indeed BigInt, but I've created a view and this one has, for some reasons, converted some columns to Decimal ...